# Create instances from list of classes

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create instances of classes from a list of classes? I've looked at other SO answers but did understand them.

I have a list of classes:

```
list_of_classes = [Class1, Class2]
```

Now I want to create instances of those classes, where the variable name storing the class is the name of the class. I have tried:

```
for cls in list_of_classes:
    str(cls) = cls()
```

but get the error: "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call". Which is of course obvious, but I don't know what to do else.

I really want to be able to access the class by name later on. Let's say we store all the instance in a dict and that one of the classes are called ClassA, then I would like to be able to access the instance by dict['ClassA'] later on. Is that possible? Is there a better way?

Comment: can't assign to a function call means the left part of `str(cls) = cls()`.You probably meant `str[cls] = cls()`. But that only works if you put `str = dict()` before the for loop. Can you try that?

Answer (score 2):

You say that you want "the variable name storing the class [to be] the name of the class", but that's a very bad idea. Variable names are not data. The names are for programmers to use, so there's seldom a good reason to generate them using code.

Instead, you should probably populate a list of instances, or if you are sure that you want to index by class name, use a dictionary mapping names to instances.

I suggest something like:

```
list_of_instances = [cls() for cls in list_of_classes]
```

Or this:

```
class_name_to_instance_mapping = {cls.__name__: cls() for cls in list_of_classes}
```

One of the rare cases where it can sometimes make sense to automatically generate variables is when you're writing code to create or manipulate class objects themselves (e.g. producing methods automatically). This is somewhat easier and less fraught than creating global variables, since at least the programmatically produced names will be contained within the class namespace rather than polluting the global namespace.

The `collections.NamedTuple` class factory from the standard library, for example, creates `tuple` subclasses on demand, with special descriptors as attributes that allow the tuple's values to be accessed by name. Here's a very crude example of how you could do something vaguely similar yourself, using `getattr` and `setattr` to manipulate attributes on the fly:

```
def my_named_tuple(attribute_names):
    class Tup:
        def __init__(self, *args):
            if len(args) != len(attribute_names):
                raise ValueError("Wrong number of arguments")
            for name, value in zip(attribute_names, args):
                setattr(self, name, value)   # this programmatically sets attributes by name!

        def __iter__(self):
            for name in attribute_names:
                yield getattr(self, name)        # you can look up attributes by name too

        def __getitem__(self, index):
            name = attribute_names[index]
            if isinstance(index, slice):
                return tuple(getattr(self, n) for n in name)
            return getattr(self, name)
    return Tup
```

It works like this:

```
>>> T = my_named_tuple(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> i = T(1, 2)
>>> i.foo
1
>>> i.bar
2
```

Comment: Thanks Blckknight! The problem is that I need to be able to access those classes later on. If I do something like class_name_to_instance_mapping = {str(cls): cls() for cls in list_of_classes}, I can't access the dict by class_name_to_instance_mapping['ClassA'] if i.e. one of the classes is called ClassA.

Comment: Ah, I guess I was careless in my example. You probably want `cls.__name__` instead of `str(cls)`. The latter gets the repr of the class, which is less convenient. I've edited the answer to give a better suggestion. Note that you could also map from the class itself to the instance if you want, without using the name at all `{cls: cls() ...}`. That might be the most convenient of all.

Answer (score 0):

If i did understood your question correctly, i think you can do something like this using `globals()`:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

class C:
    pass

def create_new_instances(classes):
    for cls in classes:
        name = '{}__'.format(cls.__name__)
        obj = cls()
        obj.__class__.__name__ = name
        globals()[name] = obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    classes = [A, B, C]
    create_new_instances(classes)
    classes_new = [globals()[k] for k in globals() if k.endswith('__') and not k.startswith('__')]
    for cls in classes_new:
        print(cls.__class__.__name__, repr(cls))
```

Output (you'll get a similar ouput):

```
A__ <__main__.A object at 0x7f7fac6905c0>
C__ <__main__.C object at 0x7f7fac6906a0>
B__ <__main__.B object at 0x7f7fac690630>
```

Comment: not a bad answer, but I can't help but think this is still a very bad idea, polluting the global namespace like that.  As we have no idea the number of instances and classes OP intends to use in this manner...

Comment: @Jason well it's the first thing that comes to my mind when i wrote this answer .... still wating the OP comment if my answer fills it's needs or not. Otherwise your comment is right.